# ObservableValidator in .NET MAUI Toolkit - doc for EventTriggerBehavior?

Tags: mvvm, maui, toolkit

In the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MVVM samples there is this XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <muxc:InfoBar
            x:Name="SuccessInfoBar"
            Title="Success"
            Message="The form was filled in correctly."
            Severity="Success">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="FormSubmissionCompleted" SourceObject="{x:Bind ViewModel}">
                    <interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                        PropertyName="IsOpen"
                        TargetObject="{x:Bind SuccessInfoBar}"
                        Value="True" />
                    <interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                        PropertyName="IsOpen"
                        TargetObject="{x:Bind FailureInfoBar}"
                        Value="False" />
                </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </muxc:InfoBar>
```

Can you tell me where I find documentation on EventTriggerBehavior? Or for that matter, where I find interactivity and Interaction.Behaviors and ChangePropertyAction?

I don't see this documented, despite searching.

Also, while I have you, this same code says

`SourceObject="{x:Bind ViewModel}`

Is Bind the same things as Binding?

Comment: EventTriggerBehavior - if you download and build that sample, you should then be able to click on `<interactions:EventTriggerBehavior` in xaml, then F12 (Go to Definition). What does it take you to? Maybe that is a class defined in the sample code itself.

Comment: `x:Bind` first time I've seen it. [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#xbind-and-binding-feature-comparison)) says `x:Bind` binds to properties of the `Page`, whereas `Binding` binds to properties of the `BindingContext` (was DataContext in UWP). That is, `x:Bind` looks in XAML for a `UI element`; `Binding` looks in your `ViewModel`. [If need more information, please start a new question. "Ask one question per question", so we have clear Q&As.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - thank you. Will try to make sure I ask only one distinct question at a time. Your clarification on x:Bind is somewhat different from the answer below, but I'll go read the docs. Thanks again.

Comment: There are several differences between `x:Bind` and `Binding`. I emphasized the most important one to know, to use successfully. In the doc link from the answer, it is in section [Property path resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path-resolution): *"{x:Bind} does not use the DataContext as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind ..."*. You'll also eventually need to understand `OneTime` vs `OneWay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EventTriggerBehavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/EventTriggerBehavior): Listens for a specific event on its source and executes an action when the event is fired, it has two configurable properties (`EventName` and `SourceObject`).

[ChangePropertyAction](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/ChangePropertyAction): Action that will change a specified property to a specified value when invoked.

For more information about Behaviors, you can check the documentation: [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki)

Regarding Bind and Binding, the [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) official document explains:

> The {x:Bind} markup extension—new for Windows 10—is an alternative to
> {Binding}. {x:Bind} runs in less time and less memory than {Binding}
> and supports better debugging.

The difference to note is that the default mode of `{x:Bind}` is `OneTime`, which is different from `{Binding}`, whose default mode is `OneWay`.

For a comprehensive comparison between `{x:Bind}` and `{Binding}`, you can read [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Comment: IMPORTANT: To use successfully, this is the most important difference between the two, from section [Property path resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path-resolution): *"{x:Bind} does not use the DataContext as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind ..."*. That is, `x:Bind` binds to properties of `the UI object`; `Binding` binds to properties of the `BindingContext` in Maui. (Was `DataContext` in older xaml environments.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - That would seem to have negative implications for MVVM  -- Typically I'm looking to bind to properties in the VM and setting the BindingContext makes that work. Am I (again) missing something?

Comment: for MVVM, one usually uses `Binding`. I think you can reach a VM property like this: `{x:Bind BindingContext.MyViewModelProperty}`. What's going on here is `x:Bind` is high-performance, but doesn't automatically connect to `BindingContext`. You have to tell it explicitly. But I don't recommend this usage, because it won't "reconnect" to the correct value, if the bound value changes. Its a **one-time** lookup. Bottom line: for MVVM, just use `Binding`.